# Рентабельность использования java.util.concurrent.*

Tags: java, многопоточность

Приветсвую, за два года опыта разработки на Java научился много чему, но и конечно что-то никогда не использовал, кроме как на этапе обучения, таким является пакет java.util.concurrent.*, для меня это пока что темный лес, принципы работы понятны, но применения пока что не понимаю, никти, очереди, блокировки и тд.

И вот пришел момент разобраться, вопрос как таковым является не вопросом, а по большей части консультацией.

У меня есть проект, в нем я использую JBDC + Postgres. Доступ к БД стандартный.
Получаю соединение-заполняю параметры-выполняю запрос-обрабатываю ResultSet-закрываю соединение. У меня всегда выполняется только одна операция, этого вполне достаточно. Но тут появилась необходимость выполнять сразу около 100 запросов однотипных. Я до этого делал стандартно, помещал все в List, далее открывал соединение, и по порядку выполнял запрос, далее в List уже записывал модели-ответы и закрывал соединение.

И тут у меня возник вопрос, а стоит ли в данном моменте например использовать многопоточность, например очереди, или разделить к примеру процесс на 10 ниток по 10 операций, будет ли это быстрее работать, и вообще будет ли это рентабельно? Стоит ли приложить усилия в изучение и применение? В изучение понятно, что пригодится, так как много вакансий где требуется знание многопоточности.

Comment: Вы можете использовать Stream API кстати. `list.parallelStream.foreach(лямбда для выполнения запроса)`. В плане скорости - потоки обычно тяжелее циклов, но если их распараллелить и если хранится большое кол-во элементов, это они могут быть быстрее

Comment: https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0

Comment: Это коннекшен пул для jdbc, если что

Comment: Нет, все таки использовать стримы была не лучшая идея. Вот что я нашел:
Внимание: крайне не рекомендуется использовать параллельные стримы для сколько-нибудь долгих операций (**получение данных из базы**, сетевых соединений), так как все параллельные стримы работают c одним пулом fork/join и такие долгие операции могут остановить работу всех параллельных стримов в JVM из-за того отсутствия доступных потоков в пуле, т.е. параллельные стримы стоит использовать лишь для коротких операций, где счет идет на миллисекунды, но не для тех где счет может идти на секунды и минуты.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ интересно, то есть эта таже JDBС, только более продвинутая, почитаю про нее.

Comment: @AntonSorokin со Stream у меня тоже пока засада, потихоньку изучаю их, и внедряю в проекты. А так спасибо за совет, у меня на один запрос уходит от 10мс до 30мс. В зависимости от сложности,так как расчеты ведутся в БД.

Comment: @Владислав аа, ну отлично. И еще: паралелльные стримы стоит использовать с большим массивом данных, т.к. если использовать с небольшими, то затраты на распараллеливание и отслеживание потоков могут первышать выигрышь от одновременного выполнения операций

Comment: @Владислав это пул соединений, он работaет поверх jdbc

Comment: Посмотрел реализацию, вроде ничего сложного, по сути нужно тольо реализовать ComboPooledDataSourse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам правильно указали на пул коннектов в комментариях, т.к. все операции с драйвером JDBC блокирующие, использование их в многопоточной среде корректно лишь с созданием некоторого количества коннектов и использованием их. Иначе, операция создания коннекта будет "сжирать" драгоценное время и никакого профита от многопоточности не будет. Еще нужно смотреть на операции в самой БД, которые также могут быть блокирующими (например вставка в таблицу, может блокировать таблицу для остальных). Таким образом можно наткнуться на lock в БД, и никак его не смочь обработать. В общем, многопоточность штука классная, но очень капризная и использовать ее нужно осторожно.

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, итог - буду разбираться, а то не знание многопоточности, как-то не есть хорошо.